# Problems with Sublime Text and Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sublimetext2

I've been using Sublime as an editor, and have been editing HTML files referencing Angular JS scripts in them. I've downloaded the Angular JS package from the "Package Control: Install Package" option, and have enabled browsers so that I can view my work in Chrome when launching it. I've been using tutorials from this site: http://learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/the-essentials, and have been using the code from the exercises in the lessons and putting them into my sublime editor, and it doesn't seem to acknowledge the Angular script.

This is an example of the code I was using to do "Two way binding" (http://learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/two-way-bindings):

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-controller="index">
    <div>
        Favorite word: <input type="text" ng-model="favoriteWord" />
        - {{favoriteWord}}
    </div>
    <div>
        Favorite color:
        <input type="radio" name="fc" value="Red" ng-model="favoriteColor">Red</input>
        <input type="radio" name="fc" value="Green" ng-model="favoriteColor">Green</input>
        <input type="radio" name="fc" value="Yellow" ng-model="favoriteColor">Yellow</input>
        <input type="radio" name="fc" value="Blue" ng-model="favoriteColor">Blue</input>
        - {{favoriteColor}}
    </div>
    <div>
        Favorite shape:
        <select ng-model="favoriteShape">
            <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
            <option value="Triangle">Triangle</option>
            <option value="Square">Square</option>
        </select>
        - {{favoriteShape}}
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module("root", [])
    .controller("index", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.favoriteWord;
        $scope.favoriteColor;
        $scope.favoriteShape;
    }]);
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when put in Sublime, it doesn't recognize the controller and bind it to the view. What am I doing wrong? Is it my code setup or something I am doing wrong with the editor?

Comment: <html ng-app="root">

Answer (score 0):

Mate, you are missing
`<html ng-app="root">`. Tell your app to use this module.
http://learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/the-essentials